# How to implement react routing with bootstrap navbar component?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, url-routing, navbar

Hi I'm new to reactjs and Im facing some difficulties in implementing routing with bootstrap navbar. Below are the pages which I created for my sample react app. Kindly anyone please help me how to modifiy the route file, so that I can easliy route with other menu options in the navbar.

Index.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Route = require('./config/routes');
var Navbar = require('./navBar');

ReactDOM.render(<Navbar/>,document.getElementById('ContactForm'))
```

Navbar.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var NavBar = React.createClass({

render: function () {

    return (
        <div className="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="navbar-header pull-left">
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li className="active"><a href="/">Home<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="/contactus">ContactUs<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="/products">Products<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
    )

}

});

module.exports = NavBar
```

route config

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;

var Navbar = require('../navBar');
var Home = require('../home');
var Contactus = require('../contactUs');
var Products = require('../product');

var routes = (

<Router>
    <Route path='/' component={Navbar}>
        <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
        <Route path='/contactus' component={Contactus}/>
        <Route path='/product' component={Products}/>
    </Route>
</Router>

);
module.exports = routes;
```

below are the different pages(menus Im planing to put in the navbar)
home.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Home = React.createClass({

render: function () {
    return (
        <div>You are in home page</div>
    )
}

});
module.exports = Home
```

contactus.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var ContactUs = React.createClass({

render: function () {
    return (
        <div>You are in Contact us page</div>
    )
}

});
module.exports = ContactUs
```

product.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Product = React.createClass({

render: function () {
    return (
        <div>You are in Product page</div>
    )
}

});
module.exports = Product
```

Anyone please help me how to modify the code in order to route through the navbar menus correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do some changes in `NavBar` Component, Use this part:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;


var NavBar = React.createClass({

    render: function () {

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="navbar-header pull-left">
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li className="active"><Link to="/home">Home<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></Link></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><Link to="/contactus">ContactUs<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></Link></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><Link to="/products">Products<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></Link></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )

    }

});

module.exports = NavBar
```

Do this part for routing:

```
var routes = (
    <Route path='/' component={Navbar}>
        <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
        <Route path='/contactus' component={Contactus}/>
        <Route path='/product' component={Products}/>
    </Route>
);
module.exports = routes;
```

Import the `history` and You this to render your route:

```
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var hashHistory = ReactRouter.hashHistory;

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>    
        {Route}    
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('ContactForm')
);
```

Changes:

*Always use `Links` instead of `href` and `a` tag, when playing with `react-router`. (read the diff between `a` and `Link`)

*You defined `NavBar` as main page (home page), and `rendering` other `components` inside it, so you need to define a place where you want to `render` these child component by `{this.props.children}`

*You are rendering the wrong component, you need to return router part, use this:
`ReactDOM.render(<Route/>,document.getElementById('ContactForm'))`

*You forgot to include the history part, Import the `hashhistory` and use it with `router`.

Read these articles on Router it will help you:

https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-router/

https://medium.com/@dabit3/beginner-s-guide-to-react-router-53094349669#.gv7fmr3oz

https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/react-router-an-introduction/

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Still the routing is not working. while clicking on the other menus in the navbar Im getting the below error.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Object.handleClick

Comment: r u using `handleClick` event at any part of the project ??

Comment: No Im not using that

Comment: But if we render the route component then we are not able to see the navbar because navbar is a separate component. I already thried this before.

Comment: Navbar is not a separate comp, it is also the part of router, you define it as home page it will be the one who hold all other comp, means your child comp will be rendered inside it, through this line `{this.props.children}`

Comment: My doubt is navbar.jsx is a seperate component and home.jsx,contactus.jsx and product.jsx are the other components which i need to route from navbar, so if we render route in index.jsx Im not able to see the navbar, if we render the navbar as i posted in question I can see the same but routing wont work. Little bit confusing to me since I'm new to react :-(

Comment: will explain everything, first lets make it work :), did some changes in ans use that part. Reason is if you didnt render the router then how ur react will know about ur routing part :). You always need to render router make all the compo as the part of react-router. Reader routes it will work :)